# save cropped image using JCrop

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, jcrop

I am cropping a image using jcrop. I am showing preview of the cropped image before saving it, as shown in [this demo page](http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/demos.php?demo=thumbnail)

Now i want to save this cropped image.

So, my question here is, will jcrop creates a new image after cropping ? So that i can directly save that new image.

Or it simply generates the co-ordinates for cropped image? so that i have to save that co-ordinates ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it just uses

```
margin-left: -25px;
margin-top: -6px;
```

so the image appear cropped inside a smaller div .
so it's doesn't in fact crop it .

in case of vertical crop it will re-size the photo as well and modify the `margin-top` .

so if you in fact save the width , height and margin of the `img` you will get your cropped image if you apply it again .

Comment: wat about height and width? only margin-left and margin-top are enough to show cropped image ?

Comment: yes thats what he is using . he uses negative values which will give the same effect as margin-bottom

Comment: okay. so now i have to save all these properties along with the image and again i have to use them when showing that image rite?

Comment: your welcome , if it works out dont forget to accept the answer :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38778/discussion-between-ranadheer-and-hussein-nazzal)